# How can I filter a map / access the entries

Tags: dart

The Map interface doesn't seem to provide access to the entries as an iterable, nor does it expose a where method to filter entries. Am I missing something? Is there a simple workaround?

e.g.

```dart
Map map;
final filteredMap = map.where((k, v) => k.startsWith("foo"));
```

Answer (score 51):

**Update**: with [control flow collection statements](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.3/control-flow-collections/feature-specification.md) you can also do this:

```
final filteredMap = {
  for (final key in map.keys)
    if (!key.startsWith('foo')) key: map[key]
};
```

**Original answer**: Dart 2.0.0 added `removeWhere` which can be used to filter Map entities. Given your example, you could apply this as:

```
Map map;
final filteredMap = Map.from(map)..removeWhere((k, v) => !k.startsWith("foo"));
```

It's not the `where` method you asked for, but filtering Map entities is certainly doable this way.

Comment: Maybe this is not not the perfect anser as you said, but it really fits to me, thanks!

Comment: What's the ".." ? I am just learning and find it impossible to search for it. Will be grateful if someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: @lost-and-found it's the cascade notation: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-

Comment: @AndrásSzepesházi Thank you very much. This also looks like a page I would want to spend some time reading. :)

Comment: Note that you should prefer `Map.of` instead of `Map.from` unless you want to create a new map with more precise types than the original one.

Comment: How would you limit to a given number of items?

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca  
final filteredMap = {  for (final key in map.keys.take(limitValue)) ....

Answer (score 7):

Since Dart 2.0 Maps have an entries getter that returns an `Iterable<MapEntry<K, V>>` so you can do:

```
MapEntry theOne = map.entries.firstWhere((entry) {
        return entry.key.startsWith('foo');
      }, orElse: () => MapEntry(null, null));
```

Comment: using your suggestion yields this error message 

type '() => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type '() => MapEntry<String, dynamic>' of 'orElse'

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```dart
library x;

void main(List<String> args) {
  Map map = {'key1': 'aölsjfd', 'key2': 'oiweuwrow', 'key11': 'oipoip', 'key13': 'werwr'};

  final filteredMap = new Map.fromIterable(
      map.keys.where((k) => k.startsWith('key1')), key: (k) => k, value: (k) => map[k]);

  filteredMap.forEach((k, v) => print('key: $k, value: $v'));
}
```

Comment: you can avoid `key: (k) => k` which is the default.

Comment: Thanks that's a pretty decent workaround. Still it really feels like a missing feature to me on map so I added https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16117

Answer (score 2):

I use [dartx](https://pub.dev/packages/dartx) and it's `filter` method

```
  var myMap = {
    "a": [1, 2, 3],
    "b": [4, 5, 6],
    "c": [7, 8, 9],
  };

  var result = myMap.filter((entry) => entry.key != "a");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just create an extension function and then use it anywhere in your code.

Put this in any file (I called mine MapUtils.dart)

```
extension MapUtils<K, V> on Map<K, V> {

  Map<K, V> where(bool Function(K, V) condition) {
    Map<K, V> result = {};
    this.entries.forEach((element) {
      if (condition(element.key, element.value)) {
        result[element.key] = element.value;
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
}
```

and then use it like so:

```
Map<String, int> peopleHeight = {"Bob":170, "Alice":130};
Map<String, int> shortPeople = peopleHeight.where((name, height) => height < 140);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the simple `where()` function:

```
final filtered = Map.fromEntries(original.entries.where((item) => ...));
```