# Dart: How to obtain a subset of a list based on a criterion?

Tags: flutter, dart

Food is a class defined as:

```
class Food {
  String name;
  double price;
  String image;
  FoodTypes foodType;
  Food({this.name, this.price, this.image, this.foodType});
}
```

The following code would return a full list of foods (defined as a list of food) after some conversion:

```
foods.map((food) {
    return FoodFrame(food);
}).toList(),
```

How can I apply the operation to a subset of foods (e.g. foodType == 'fruit') only?

Comment: I believe your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21130889/2516576).

Comment: `[for (var food in foods) if (food.foodType == 'fruit') FoodFrame(food)]`

Comment: worked perfectly. Thanks!